# Tls Error while configure MQTT in awsiot

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

mosquitto_sub --cafile rootCA.pem --cert cert.pem --key privateKey.pem -h a3380wclf1r5nk.iot.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -d -t lights/things/things01 -i thing01

***Error: Unable to load client key file "privateKey.pem".
   Unable to connect (A TLS error occurred.).***
Please help in this i am stuck

Comment: Is the private key file password protected?

Comment: no that's i have imported @hardillb

Comment: Double check what format privateKey.pem actually is. Openssl is probably the best tool to check with